# No resource found when building AOSP's Dialer

Tags: android, android-studio

I cloned the dialer code from Google (https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Dialer/), imported the project to Android studio, I am getting the following error while making the project.

```
C:\Users\san16\Desktop\Dialer\app\src\main\res\values\styles.xml
Error:(33, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'activated_background'.
Error:(58, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'contact_browser_background'.
Error:(56, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'contact_browser_list_padding_left'.
and so on
```

other stackoverflow thread suggested to change compileSdkVersion to 21 in the gradle, but mine already is !

my build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion '21.1.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.android.dialer"
        testApplicationId "com.android.dialer.tests"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 21
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
}
```

Help!

Comment: The individual apps of the AOSP are not designed to be built on their own, but only as part of a full firmware build. Those symbols probably come from other aspects of Android that are not part of the Android SDK.

Comment: Why are you trying to build those apps? Why don't you start with something simpler to learn from?

Comment: @JaredBurrows I am trying to write my own app which receives and makes call, I couldn't find any resource which helps me to achieve that, I just wanted to see how Android Vanilla has implemented it!

Comment: @CommonsWare That seems to be an odd Design to compile every single Layers to build a single App!, Can i work around this issue?

Comment: "Can i work around this issue?" -- I have no idea.

Comment: @user2067797 I know what you are trying to do. That's why I am suggesting starting on something small. Also, you can see the source code of the Dialer app(you have it downloaded). You do not need to compile it's code, create your own app and slowly integrate parts of their code. You will have to do this anyways.

Answer (score 1):

This res value is a part of a ContactsCommon
First import https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/ContactsCommon/

and use it as a library project.